# SpringBoot : RestAPI data not populating in JSON format. (? Solution)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

**Issue :**
Getting data in below format but I want in JSON format so I can bind it.

[[1,"User"],[2,"Visitor"]]   <-- This data I want in JSON format

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ccCategory,Integer>
{

    public static final String FIND_CATEGORYNAME = "SELECT DISTINCT catID,categoryName from XXCategory";

    @Query(value = FIND_CATEGORYNAME, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> getCategoryName();

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
public class HomeResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeResource.class);

    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;



@GetMapping("/getAllCategory")
        public List<Object> getAllCategory() {
        System.out.println("***** Call : API getAllCategory() ******");
        List<Object> cCategory = categoryRepository.getCategoryName();
        return cCategory;
    }
```

Comment: Read the docs and understand the tools you have available. You can use a Spring Data Projection to return a subset of fields. No SQL  squery returning an array of objects required. Job done. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Answer (score 0):

That is still valid JSON!

If you want to wrap it inside an object, you need to create a response model as follows:

```
public class Categories implements Serializable {

    public List<Object> category;
}
```

I would also suggest you expand on this and create a `Category` entity rather than making use of an `Object`. This will create a mapping for the fields within the nested arrays as well. From your repository I can see you already have some sort of `Category` entity, so maybe you can reuse that.

Your controller can then return `Categories` or better yet `ResponseEntity<Categories>` to return a proper response. In which case, you can return `cCategory` wrapped inside the `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.ok` method.

You can also skip the `Categories` object and make use of the `Category` entity. It depends on what you're after. It would help if you provide an expected output.